# The coarsest topology finer than two topologies on the same set

Tags: general-topology

If T3 is the coarsest topology finer than T1 and T2, and U in T3 then we have
Three cases:
Case 1. U in T1.
Case 2. U in T2.
Case 3. U neither in T1 nor in T2. what conditions should be added to the bitopological space (X, T1, T2) such that the third case must be U = K union L, where K in T1 and L in T2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I think it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need arbitrary unions of intersections between open sets of $T_1$ and of $T_2$, i.e., $T_3$ consists of all
$$\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\cap V_i) $$
with $U_i\in T_1$ and $V_i\in T_2$.

For example, consider $\Bbb R$ and let $T_1$ be the topology of all sets of the form $(a,\infty)$, and $T_2$ that of all sets of the form $(-\infty,b)$. Then $T_3$ turns out to be the standard topology of $\Bbb R$

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. hat you've basically done is defined $T_3$. The OP is asking under what circumstances is an open set in $T_3$ not an open set in either $T_1$ or $T_2$. I'm not sure there is a good answer in general, but that is (I believe) the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have clarified the question now.